# Page copying fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, episerver, episerver-6-r2

I have a problem with copy/paste action in the episerver tree.

When I try to copy and paste a page the background job is run, however it fails with an error:

> Failed to copy the page "Test Content page" beneath the page "Home".

Have you ever come across such a situation? Is it a matter of rights maybe?

Comment: Have you checked the log (remember to set log level to e.g. Debug in EPiServerLog.config)? 
Verified that you have permissions to create pages beneath "Home"?
Done this while debugging in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this issue before. It was because the Page Type of the child page was not in the available page types of the parent page.

You can check this by looking at your home page type in admin mode, clicking the settings button and then selecting the available page types tab. Ensure the page type of your test content page is allowed.

if you are using pagetype builder you will also need to update your page type in code.

Comment: I've tried that before. But if this is be the case I would get a popup saying that this page type is not allowed a this location.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a single page or a partial tree? If it's a tree it could still be problem with subpages whose types aren't allowed under your copied page or it's subpages.